# libGDX: how to scale the texture itself in small resolution

Tags: android, libgdx, textures

I have read [libGDX: Scale Textures when smaller resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389684/libgdx-scale-textures-when-smaller-resolution) but that is not my case.

I know how to adapt to the screen resolution using something like `Viewport`, but if the resolution is very small e.g. 300*300, load an HD picture (e.g. 1024*1024) into memory is wasteful. The picture is read dynamically, not pre-packaged by me, so I have to scale according to the screen size when loading the texture.

In Andorid, I can ues `inSampleSize` to downsample while decoding pictures to bitmap, I can also use `Bitmap.createBitmap()` to get a reduced image. Both methods can effectively save memory. But in libGDX I failed to find a similar solution, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You're right! HD pictures loading on small screen resolutions is wasteful. Don't need to scale images (sometimes it's even bad), just make your images in different resolutions. Next on create, check your screen resolution and load desired pack of images.

Comment: Thanks but this plan is not suitable for me. This is a DIY-like function, the picture is freely selected by the user. So I cannot guarantee the resolution of the picture.